# Tortoise SVN tracking changes with single login computer?

Tags: authentication, tortoisesvn, blame

I have a development machine that we use to change file and we have SVN as our CM tool. We only have a single login to the computer itself. Is there a way to track the changes in the repository someway even if we have a single computer login?

In other words...

Computer has 3 users: A, B, C

The computer only has one login.

So if user A changes something, and then user B changes something. How can I differentiate the two changes?

Comment: Do you have Single Sign-On on SVN server or something?

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN should prompt you to enter the credentials to authenticate. If this doesn't happen -- you can clear authentication cache. See [TortoiseSVN manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug.html#tsvn-dug-general-auth) for further details.

If you use VisualSVN Server with [Integrated Windows Authentication (Single Sign-On)](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/windows-auth/#integrated) you need to manage Active Directory credentials with Windows Credential Manager. Check the [ServerFault thread](https://serverfault.com/a/408830/107134) for instruction.